# Modal page Automation using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, modal-dialog, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java and selenium webdriver for WebAutomation. The scenario is like, when we click on the particular option the new Modal page gets opened. However, with help of Webdriver, when I click on that particular option the modal page is not getting opened. Please suggest me how can do this

Comment: Is the problem that your website is failing to open the modal page, when webdriver clicks on the option?

Answer (score 0):

It seems **Click()** is not happening on the *Particular* Option which opens up the modal page